# How to create an image gallery on flutter?

Tags: flutter, image-gallery

I have a `Set<String>` variable containing a list of image files. In a `Card` object, in addition to some `Text` elements, I want to create a gallery of images like this:

[image]

The number of images stored in `Set<String>` is variable. If possible, I want to show in a corner (top-right) the current number image and the total count of images (e.g. 1/5).

The images will be withdrawn from a webserver, and I don't know if it's more efficient to save them in cache or not. I don't want to use storage folder to save the images.

If possible, I would to withdraw all the images in a single http request, to save time.

Here the variable:

```
Set<String> _photosList = {
'http://myhost.com/image01.jpg',
'http://myhost.com/image02.bmp',
'http://myhost.com/image03.png',
'http://myhost.com/image04.gif',
};
```

Comment: Hey, did you try implementing something on your own? SO isn't a platform where code gets written for you, it's only there to ask questions on exiting code and to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Hey, check out the answer, and let me know if that is what you were looking for?

Comment: I used your solution replacing Positioned with Align, and not it's as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain things which I want you to explore before actually jumping into the code. These are:

- [PageView class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html), this will help you know about how this scrolling thing works like Gallery View. Also, will tell you how the `nextPage` and `previousPage` works with the icon clicks
- [PageController class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html) how the pages works inside the `PageView`
- [Stack class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), for aligning your arrow on top of your gallery

Let us now jump to the code how it works. *Follow the comments to know about each work*

```
  // this will keep track of the current page index
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  
  // this is your page controller, which controls the page transition
  final PageController _controller = new PageController();
  
  Set<String> _photosList = {
    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRqRwpDKN_zJr1C7pPeWcwOa36BtPm4HeLPgA&usqp=CAU',
    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSgjZ8pw5WLIGMBibVi_g4CMlSE-EOvrLv7Ag&usqp=CAU',
    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQUuMIENOhc1DmruZ6SwLc7JtrR6ZMBRAb3jQ&usqp=CAU',
    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRzasDrBHWV-84vxbmlX7MTuz3QHqtT8jtTuA&usqp=CAU'
  };
```

Now the UI of the Gallery View.

**Please note:** This code supports, swipe functionality in the view. If you want to disable it just add this line inside your `Pageview.builder()`

```
physics:new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

```
         Container(
            // use MediaQuery always, it will always adjust the dimensions
            // according to different screens
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
            // here is your stack
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                // PageView.builder is just the part of PageView, read through
                // Documentation, and you will get to know
                PageView.builder(
                  controller: _controller,
                  // here you can remove swipe gesture. UNCOMMENT IT 
                  // physics:new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                  onPageChanged: (index){ 
                    // with each change updating the index of our variable too
                    setState(() => _pageIndex = index);
                  },
                  itemCount: _photosList.length,
                  // building the view of our gallery
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position){
                    return Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: NetworkImage(_photosList.elementAt(position))
                          )
                        )
                      )
                    );
                  }
                ),
                
                // this will come over the images, the icon buttons
                Positioned(
                  left: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          // checking if we are not on pos = 0
                          // then we can always go back else do nothing
                          if(_pageIndex != 0)
                            _controller.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.white, size: 28.0)
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          // checking if we are not on pos = photosList.length - 1
                          // we calculate 0 to length-1
                          // then we can always go forward else do nothing
                          if(_pageIndex < _photosList.length-1)
                            _controller.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.white, size: 28.0)
                      ),
                    ]
                  )
                )
              ]
            )
          )
```

**Result**

[image: Result GIF]

**Pointer:** In order to show them numbering on the corner. just make use of two variables which is already there for you in the code

- `_pageIndex`, keeps an update of the page changes
- `_photosList.length`, which gives you the total count of the images

Do something like this, and show it using `Container` in the same view:

```
//_pageIndex + 1, because it starts from 0 not 1, and goes up to 4 not 5
Text('${_pageIndex+1}/$_photosList.length')
```